# No qualifying bean of type RsaProperties when upgrading to Edgware.SR3

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to update from Spring Cloud Edgware.SR2 to Edgware.SR3. When I build the Spring Cloud Config Server the default contextLoads test in ApplicationTests fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionBootstrapConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'encryptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.DefaultTextEncryptorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'locator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.EncryptionAutoConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rsaProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.RsaProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I suspect that this is the result of [this change in Spring Cloud Commons](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/334). I have `encrypt.rsa` configuration in my `bootstrap.yml` file which is working in Edgware.SR2 and I've tried adding `compile( "org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa" )` to `build.gradle`.

With Spring Boot 1.5.14 and Spring Cloud Edgware.SR3 ([Spring Cloud Config 1.4.3 and Spring Cloud Commons 1.3.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes)), it is only the test that fails. If I comment out the test, build and then run, it starts successfully and decrypts my configuration. If I go to start.spring.io to create a new Spring Cloud Config project, added my `application.yml`, my `bootstrap.yml` and include `spring-security-rsa` the test fails and the service fails to start due to the above error.

1. What change would I need to make in order to for the default test to pass on Spring Boot 1.5.14 and Spring Cloud Edgware.SR3 with Spring Cloud Config that uses RSA encrypted data?
2. What would I need to do to get both the test to pass and the service to run with Spring Boot 2.0.3 and Spring Cloud Finchley?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Spencer Gibb showed [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/385#issuecomment-402228441), the problem was that when `encrypt.keyStore.location` is specified then `encrypt.keyStore.password` is required (source code [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/71d8df14c7b88470feaa2fc0f97cc8d474d9728d/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EncryptionAutoConfiguration.java#L100)). `encrypt.keyStore.location` should be moved to be specified through profiles in `bootstrap.yml`, so that `encrypt.keyStore.password` isn't required for the test.