# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.RsaProperties'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting a nosuchbean exception as the title suggests, just adding text here to satisfy the mostly code thing.

Have put unlimited crypto jars in jre\lib\security

Key store created in application at src\main\resources and is called config-server.jks

application.properties (tried both key-stores location prop definitions)

```
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=ssh://git@v00bitbucket:7999/proj/config-server.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
security.user.name=Joe
security.user.password={bcrypt}$2a$10$7H8tnjyf/Mn90eAZADruterXJ.t.GQP4WgRIZ8cwnRsMmhZhCtS1a
#encrypt.key-store.location=classpath:/config-server.jks
encrypt.key-store.location=file://C:/myAppDir/config- server/src/main/resources/config-server.jks
encrypt.key-store.password=my-s70r3-s3cr3t
encrypt.key-store.alias=config-server-key
encrypt.key-store.secret=my-k34-s3cr3t
```

using java 1.8.0_77

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ConfigServerApplicationTests {    
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}    


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.user.name}")
    private String authUser;
    @Value("${security.user.password}")
    private String authPassword; // this password is encoded
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder())
        .withUser(authUser).password(authPassword).roles("User");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

here is the pom
{

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

}

Comment: here is the keytool command:
 
    keytool -genkeypair -alias config-server-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -sigalg SHA512withRSA -dname "CN=Config Server,OU=Spring,O=MyOrg" -keypass my-k34-s3cr3t -keystore config-server.jks -storepass my-s70r3-s3cr3t

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: no idea how to add a stack trace, due to limited chars in comment

Comment: @user1346730 you should edit the post to add the stack trace.

Comment: just a quick question. I see that the keystore location has a space in "config- server" is that correct? Also, the error stack trace would help a lot...

Comment: One more thing, this problem seems very similar to another question so it could be worth checking it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069326/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-rsaproperties-when-upgrading-to-edgware-sr3

Comment: @Shihe Zhang yep, tried that, cannot 'due to limited chars in comment'

Comment: @gmcontessa tried using keytool command (and keystore) where CN=config-server, same result...

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into this problem too.

My best guess is that it is a bug in the latest version of Spring Cloud.  I will open an issue on Spring Cloud project and link it here once finished.

I am using application.yml, not application.properties.

When you put any config for encrypt: * in application yml, it will give you this error.  As a work-a-round, I tried putting the encrypt:* config in **bootstrap.yml**

After that, the Spring Boot app started successfully and it will have the *RsaProperties* Bean :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1122) to issue opened on Github.